# getting route/object%20object in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

Recently we have been migrated to laravel4.2 to laravel 5.2 every phase we have completed and the application working fine. But the issue is when we access show routes.
`we are getting one error like`

> routename/object%20object in url even though

we are getting this error but `application works fine`.
we are using nginx in development and production.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you get this error when you run `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: No when we are running application i am getting  error like /employees/[object%20Object] for all show methods iam getting this error in log but those routes working fine i dont understand why those 404 errors coming.

Comment: Do you have any route starting with `/employess/` ? If yes, please comment it and verify if you are getting this error for other routes.

Comment: yes i have that route but the error coming for other routes also.

Comment: Have you commented out this route? Do you still have errors for other routes? Do you use model route binding?

Comment: yes i commented actually the error appears occasionally when we open the route first time the error appears after that it is not appearing.

Answer (score -1):

Just run php artisan cache:clear

Or delete all files in storage/framework/views

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you rakesh my problem solved.Its due to ajax issue.

Comment: @PoornaRao what ajax issue? you should write answer when you find the solution